Laravel vapor site throws 500 error in production during login
I have a vapor hosted site, and whenever the users try to login, it throws a 500 error since yesterday
During troubleshooting, I checked the logs and noticed that the error might be related to RDS certificate. I logged into the EC2 instance, and updated the certificate because the vapor dashboard indicated of its expiry for yesterday.
The RDS certificate is updated, however, I am still struggling with the site login.
Could this be cache related? If so, how do I clear the caches?
From the vapor dashboard, I run "artisan chache:clear" command, but the command throws the following error:
In DynamoDbStore.php line 451:
                                                                           
DynamoDb does not support flushing an entire table. Please create a new tab  

le.
I do not recall setting up a dynamo cache at all, and neither I do see it in the environment variables.
Note: The site works perfectly fine locally.
How do I fix this?
